# Current Population Survey (CPS) before 1962

Tags: data-request, economics

I am trying to find monthly CPS data for years before 1962, which is the first year available through IPUMS. I checked on the NBER website but they only provide data from 1976 on. CPS should have been administered since the 1940s but I cannot find an online source of data for the first two decades.

Do you know if they are available? And if yes, where?

Answer (score 0):

That was long ago and I doubt you'd find it. Write to the bea directly and see if they can help.  It is likely a analog  microfiche lost in some cabinet. Good luck. Most data before the eighties was never digitized. You will need to travel to it.